# bxslider change width onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

I have a menu next to my bxslider which i can slide in and out.
Therefore my slider is going to resize itself. When I do this bxslider is either hiding parts of my images or showing already parts of the next slide.

I solved this by destroying and reloading the slider. I need to wait until the css transition is finished otherwise it doesn't work but it looks pretty strange now. Is there another solution for my problem?

edit: I would like it too look like when you resize the window with the responsive slider. So no jumping transitions.

http://jsfiddle.net/r6fvg3ov/2/

```
<section id="work">
<div id="navigation" class="hidden"> 
    <a href="javascript:;" id="menu-btn" class="menu-btn"><span></span></a>

    <ul class="main">
        <li><a data-slide-index="2">men1</a>

            <ul class="sub1">
                <li><a data-slide-index="1">men2.1</a>

                    <ul class="sub2">
                        <li><a data-slide-index="1">men2.1.1</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a data-slide-index="2">men2.1.2</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a data-slide-index="0">men2.1.3</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a data-slide-index="1">men2.2</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="slider" class="full">
    <div class="gallery">
        <ul class="bxslider">
            <li>
                <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_trees.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/me_trees.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/houses.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_fence.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/trees.jpg" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

this is my solution so far:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
     pagerCustom: '#navi',
 });

 $('#menu-btn').click(function () {
     $('#navigation').toggleClass('visible');
     $('#navigation').toggleClass('hidden');
     $('#slider').toggleClass('resized');
     $('#slider').toggleClass('full');
     setTimeout(function () {
         slider.destroySlider();
         slider.reloadSlider();
     }, 500);

 });

});
```

thank you for your help!

Comment: one remark/comment : it's always useful to use English words as function names, classes, that will make non German speakers to understand and help you with your code.

Comment: A live example might be useful too. Try to make a jsfiddle for us, your question isn't so easy to understand...

Comment: @kartsims you can use the SO functiobnality, "Run Code Snippet" - full page

Comment: ok did the changes hope it's better to understand now

Answer (score 1):

JSFiddle does not load for me atm., but I think this should do the job:

```
    $('#slider')
            .toggleClass('resized')
            .toggleClass('full')
            .on('oanimationend animationend webkitAnimationEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd',function(){
        slider.destroySlider();
        slider.reloadSlider();
    })
```

Just run .on('...') event listener on the DOM object being animated (in your case it's $('#slider') I believe)

Comment: i already tried this solution but it didn't work for me, because bxslider doesn't change.

Comment: The best hack I could imagine: http://jsfiddle.net/r6fvg3ov/26/
Not perfect on higher resolutions, but gives an idea of what needs to be done.

Unfortunately, bfslider does not support good enough, case like you have

Comment: yeah i know this is very tricky! i can just imagine that a solution could be that i use the function which is handling the responsive part of bxslider! But i have no idea how this can be done

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6fvg3ov/12/)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
     pagerCustom: '#navi'
 });

 $('#menu-btn').click(function () {
     $('#navigation').toggleClass('visible');
     $('#navigation').toggleClass('hidden');
     $('#slider').toggleClass('resized');
     $('#slider').toggleClass('full');
     $('#navigation').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', 
         function(e) { slider.redrawSlider();
     });
 });
```

});

Comment: thank you for the code improvement, but it still looks very jumpy when the slider is resizing. it should change it's size just the way it changes when you resize the window (responsive)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the jsfiddle.

I don't think you can do this... You are mixing two different and independant concepts : JS resizing and CSS transitions.

You might achieve to synchronize them (poorly) by setting the same animation time as the css transition time, but this doesn't sound like a good solution to me.

I would drop the css transitions and use a full JS solution. This won't look great when you resize the window manually but you may end up with a nice resizing animation when the menu appears/disappears...

Comment: yeah i know! i think i prefer a nice look when resizing the window and ignore the slider gallery problem

Comment: Sure, I agree on this one